# Match values to all members of comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a search query that matches all values of partial string. I would like to use comma delimited string as an input.

| Item Description |
| --- |
| One Apple |
| Two Apples |
| Three Apples |

Input string: `'app, o'`

Desired outcome:

```
One Apple
Two Apples
```

Comment: Where is your search criteria coming from - could you pass data in a table data type?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Stu. I can pass it as a parameter and use string_split to create a temporary table. But that is equivalent to OR statement, but I am looking for AND. I can create a stored procedure but was hoping there is a way to utilize just query

Comment: @Larnu. it is 2019

Comment: There's no SQL Server 2018. The oldest version still in mainstream support is SQL Server 2017. After that it's 2019 and the upcoming version is 2022.

Comment: @goryef using string_split is the logical solution.

Comment: `string_split` has nothing to do with `OR` or `AND`. It simply splits a string into a table of values. What you do with those values is up to you. What you try to do though will result in bad performance even if the values were already in another table. Searching for substrings is *slow* because it can't use any indexes.

Comment: If you really want to search for  arbitrary text you should use [Full Text Search indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) and [FTS queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16). FTS queries take care of stemming and synonyms, so searching for `Apple` will return rows with `Apples` and vice versa

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. The key for me is to find ALL partial values in a input string. It's a key word search of a long descriptions.

Comment: That's what FTS queries are for. You can write an overly complicated and extremely slow query that joins the split results with a `LIKE` condition instead of equality, or you can use FTS queries and functions that easily handle `AND`, `NEAR` and even allow weighting different terms

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Thank You. I will look into FTS. Seems very promising.

Comment: You're already using FTS searches in Google and Bing